# Delete first result only from SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is the code I'm running:

```sql
DELETE FROM fosters_user 
WHERE user_id = (SELECT "admin" FROM fosters_user);
```

I also tried something else I found here on the forum:

```sql
DELETE FROM fosters_user 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM fosters_user 
                  WHERE user_id = "admin" LIMIT 1)
```

Table name = `fosters_user`

My data:

| user_id | test1 | test2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| admin | 2 | 1 |
| admin | 5 | 6 |

What I want to do is to run a SQL command to delete only 1 of the rows, but for some reason it deletes both of them.

I'm not sure what my mistake is.

Comment: How do you determine which row is the first row? which column would you order by?

Comment: Do the rows have unique IDs?  If they don't, it will likely not be possible to determine which one to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete only based on the `user_id` as you are attempting, you will delete all the records with that `user_id`. You must be able to distinguish the records.

The following describes how the first record of each `user_id` may be deleted.

SQLITE tables have a [`ROWID`](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) if you do not have an autoincrementing column in your schema. if you do, then you may substitute it below. The following demo and proposed solutions recreated your schema as shared (i.e. without an auto incrementing field) and as such uses the `ROWID` from sqlite.

You may use a window function `ROW_NUMBER` to determine the first occurrence and delete from your table by matching the filtered row id.

**BEFORE**

```
select * from fosters_user;
```

| user_id | test1 | test2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| admin | 2 | 1 |
| admin | 5 | 6 |

---

**OPTION 1: DELETE WHEN JUST CONSIDERING ONE USER ID**

```sql
DELETE FROM fosters_user
WHERE ROWID IN  (
    SELECT MIN(ROWID) as row_id
    FROM fosters_user
    WHERE  user_id = "admin"
) ;
```

**OPTION 2: DELETE WHEN CONSIDERING MULTIPLE USER IDs**

This approach is also useful if you would like to determine the first occurrence of your record based on the order of another field. You may simply update the `(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ROWID)` to `(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY your_column_of_choice)`.

```
DELETE FROM fosters_user
WHERE ROWID IN  (
    SELECT row_id FROM (
        SELECT 
            ROWID as row_id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ROWID) rn
        FROM fosters_user
    ) t
    WHERE rn = 1 and user_id = "admin"
) ;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**AFTER**

```
select * from fosters_user;
```

| user_id | test1 | test2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| admin | 5 | 6 |

---

[View Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mLQj8nr3jv3PSunzvPmwC7/2)

Let me know if this works for you.